# Wordpress gutenberg block serverside rendering html elements not showing up

Tags: block-editor

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import ServerSideRender  from '@wordpress/server-side-render'
import {useBlockProps}  from '@wordpress/block-editor'

registerBlockType('fsm/custom-logo-block',{
    title:"Fsm Logo",
    description:"Adres Eklemek İçin Kullanabilirsiniz.",
    icon:"format-gallery",
    category:"widgets",
    attributes:{
        width:"string",
        heigth:"string"
    },
    edit:function({attributes,setAttributes}){
        return (
            <div {...useBlockProps()}>
                <h1>Web Site Logo</h1> // this does not appear
                <input placeholder='width' onChange={(e)={setAttributes({width:e.target.value})}}/>
                <input placeholder='height' onChange={(e)=>{setAttributes({heigth:e.target.value})}}/>
                <ServerSideRender block="fsm/custom-logo-block"/>
            </div>
        )
    },
    save:function({attributes}){
        return null
    }

})
```

```
<?php 
function logoRender(){
                $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod('custom_logo');
                $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom_logo_id,'full');
                $alt = get_bloginfo("name");
                if(has_custom_logo()){
                    return '<img class="logo" src="'.esc_url($logo[0]).'" alt="'.$alt.'"';
                }
                else{
                    return "<h1 class='found'>Logo Bulunamadı</h1>";
                } 
}
function fsm_gutenberg_blocks(){
    wp_register_script('fsm-custom-logo-block',get_template_directory_uri().'/build/index.js',array('wp-blocks'));
    register_block_type("fsm/custom-logo-block",array(
        'render_callback' => "logoRender",
        'editor_script' => 'fsm-custom-logo-block'
    ));
}
add_action('init','fsm_gutenberg_blocks')
?>
```

Comment: Where’s your server-side code? Also, you‘ve only passed `custom-logo-block`, but your block’s name is `fsm/custom-logo-block`.

Comment: I edited it to 'fsm/custom-logo-block' but it's the same

Comment: "`// this does not appear`" - maybe it's just hidden via CSS? Try inspecting the DOM and see if the element is there. I also spotted other issues in your code - 1) Your attributes are not properly defined, e.g. `width:"string"` should be `width: { type: "string" }` 2) Possible typo - "heigth" - shouldn't it be `height` instead? 3) `<input placeholder='width' onChange={(e)={` - you forgot an `>` there, i.e. `=>`. 4) Your inputs aren't displaying the attribute's value, e.g. `value={ attributes.width }`.

Comment: Did you check that you did everything else right? Did you install all necessary npm packages? Did you compile script with webpack (@wordpress/script is also needed, since you are using this`@wordpress/blocks` import shortcut?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I solved the problem.

Comment: @MustafaDalkılıç can you write an answer, and explain how exactly did you or what you did to solve the problem? 

Comment: I did server side rendering from the save property not edit

Comment: So that was the problem, right? Can you just please write an answer - a simple one like `The problem was ..... and I solved it by .....` would do.

Comment: yes, did you solve it with the method I said so simple?

Comment: Well, I did not have to solve it, it's your code, and when I tested it a few days ago, I used `ServerSideRender` in `edit`, just like it is currently in your post/question. So, writing your own answer would be beneficial to others, including myself, even if the problem was as simple as a typo.